# JavaScript subclassing and method overriding

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I want to make simple classic inheritance with JavaScript. I just need sub classing and method overriding and not the verbose syntax and bells and whistles as provided by prototype.js or some of the other libraries.

Now, this fellow named Shelby S. Moore has come up with a solution that works just the way I want it to:
http://www.coolpage.com/developer/javascript/Correct%20OOP%20for%20Javascript.html

Only problem is that he is extending native types Object and Function which breaks some of the libraries I use. Also as a general observation I don't want to mess with the prototypes of native objects.

I've made Shelby S. Moore's example live here:
http://jsfiddle.net/christian1974/CEKL5/

As you can see from the example it works as expected.
Now, the $64.000 question is: Can you recommend a way of making it work without messing with Object.prototype and Function.prototype?

I was looking for a really simple syntax like:

```
Extend(parent, this);
```

Should I just drop the whole idea and go with an existing library that does this? Am I making life too difficult for my self?

Comment: I'm afraid, you don't have subclassing in JS. It's a prototypal language not a class-based one. Also, the best solution is to create an own namespace/Object and just augment this one instead of messing with the native objects, though when doing it right, extending these is okay too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not, instead of augmenting the object prototype, just create a function `inherits`?

```
function inherits(parent)
{
    //just make sure this doesn't get called on the global object (like a regular function)
    //and the parent is an actual constructor reference
    if (this === window || typeof parent !== 'function')
    {
        throw new Error('inherit not possible on window/without constructor');
    }
    //to set the constructor dynamically and secure the constructor of child object
    //I'd say this should do the trick (be weary though, not tested)
    var constr, Proto;
    constr = this.constructor;
    Proto = typeof parent === 'function' ? new parent : parent;//get instance
    this.prototype = Proto.prototype;
    this.constructor = constr;//restore constructor when needed
    if( arguments.length > 1 )
    {
        return parent.apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ) );
    }
    return parent.call( this );
}

function Foo(someArg)
{
    inherits.apply(this,[Bar,someArg]);
}
```

That being said, I don't really see the benefits of this method over, say, `Object.create` and -since you're using libs- jQuery's `.extend` method

Comment: This is almost perfect! Only thing.. Prototype of the parent class is not passed on to the subclass.

Comment: I've updated the code to address that. Not tested but _in theory_ this should work

Comment: Look what I found! Just what I was looking for: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Comment: :) I'll read it later today, looks interesting. It feels good to see some of the things I suggested being used by John Resig himself. At first glance, his code goes a step further than mine, though: it's neigh on cloning the object. Anyway, thanks for the link! Also, since you've accepted this answer: can I have my $64,000 now (I am prepared to share it with John Resig, so $32,000 is an acceptable fee :-P)

Answer (score 1):

```
function extend(Child, Parent) {
    var F = function() { };
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype;
    Child.prototype = new F();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
    Child.superclass = Parent.prototype;
}
```

Usage:

```
function Parent() {}

Parent.prototype.hello = function(name) {
    alert('hello ' + name);
}

function Child() {
    Child.superclass.hello.call(this, 'world');
}

extend(Child, Parent);
```

Comment: Thanks Wade. How would you pass arguments to super?

Comment: I have attached it to the answer.